# subscribeOn doesn't apply to entire Rx Chain, causes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have this subject that is subscribed to in my `CommonLocationManager` class, which provides `android.location.Location` updates to its subscribers.

```
public class CommonLocationManager {

    private final Subject<CommonLocationEvent> mCommonLocationEventSubject = PublishSubject.<CommonLocationEvent>create().toSerialized();

    public Observable<CommonLocationEvent> registerSubscription(@NonNull String identifier, LocationRequestType locationRequestType) {
        boolean alreadySubscribed = mSubscribers.containsKey(identifier);

        if (alreadySubscribed) {
            Log.e(TAG + ": " + identifier + " is already subscribed (or not unique)");
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG + ": " + identifier + " subscribed");
            queueLocationRequest(locationRequestType);
            mSubscribers.put(identifier, locationRequestType);
        }

        return mCommonLocationEventSubject;
    }
}
```

The subject receives its onNext values from the `android.location.LocationListener` that we use.

```
private android.location.LocationListener mLocationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCommonLocationEventSubject.onNext(new CommonLocationEvent(location));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //no op
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //no op
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //no op
    }
};
```

This is subscribed to in this code block, which receives `CommonLocationEvent`s (from the subject), gets the `android.location.Location` object from it, and then loads a `Foo` based on that location. The `flatMap` block's `CurrentLocationFooProvider.getFooForCurrentLocation(coordinate)` makes an API call.

```
MyApplication.getInstance()
    .commonLocationManager()
    .registerSubscription(TAG, getRequestType())
    .filter(new Predicate<CommonLocationEvent>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull CommonLocationEvent commonLocationEvent) throws Exception {
            final boolean isLocationEvent = commonLocationEvent.getEventType() == CommonLocationEvent.EventType.LOCATION_UPDATE &&
        commonLocationEvent.getLocation() != null;

            final boolean enoughTimeHasElapsed = Math.abs(mLastUpdateTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) > getRefreshInterval();

            final boolean shouldQueueNewRequest = isLocationEvent && enoughTimeHasElapsed;
            Log.v(TAG + " ShouldQueueNewRequest is " + String.valueOf(shouldQueueNewRequest));
            return shouldQueueNewRequest;
        }
    })
    .map(new Function<CommonLocationEvent, Coordinate>() {
        @Override
        public Coordinate apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull CommonLocationEvent commonLocationEvent) throws Exception {
            return Coordinate.fromNullableLocation(commonLocationEvent.getLocation());
        }
    })
    .filter(new Predicate<Coordinate>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Coordinate coordinate) throws Exception {
            return !Coordinate.isEffectivelyNull(coordinate);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Function<Coordinate, Observable<Foo>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Foo> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Coordinate coordinate) throws Exception {
            return new CurrentLocationFooProvider().getFooForCurrentLocation(coordinate)
        .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, Foo>() {
            @Override
            public Foo apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                return Foo.NULL;
            }
        });
        }
    })
    .filter(new Predicate<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Foo foo) throws Exception {
            return !Foo.NULL.equals(foo);
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new Observer<Foo>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            mDisposable = d;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Foo foo) {
            Log.v(TAG + " onNext");

            if (foo != null) {
                mLastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(foo.getName())) {
        Log.v(TAG + " New foo is " + foo.getName());
                }

                onNewFoo(foo);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e);
            unsubscribe();
            setupSubscription();
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.e(TAG + " onComplete");
        }
    });
```

I receive a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` from the Rx stream, even though I have `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in the chain. Note that the CurrentLocationFooProvider doesn't add its own `subscribeOn` or `observeOn` If I change the flat map to include its own `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, the api call will be successful, as seen here:

```
.flatMap(new Function<Coordinate, Observable<Foo>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Foo> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Coordinate coordinate) throws Exception {
            return new CurrentLocationFooProvider().getFooForCurrentLocation(coordinate)
        .onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, Foo>() {
            @Override
            public Foo apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                return Foo.NULL;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }
    })
```

A part of me is okay with this because it works, but I don't understand why this `subscribeOn` is necessary, since I subscribe to subjects and make API calls in flat maps elsewhere in the codebase without this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `subscribeOn` has its propagation limits and doesn't just apply to dynamically creates source such as those in your `flatMap`. In these cases, you have to apply `subscribeOn` on the inner `Observables` you are flatMapping.

Comment: @akarnokd the weird thing is that I do this in other places with impunity. It seems odd that in this case it just arbitrarily isn't being applied.

Comment: `subscribeOn` changes where the subscription side-effects of the upstream happen. In your case, it appears you subscribe to a `Subject` which has no practical effect and you signal values through that subject from the main thread I guess. That triggers a subscription in the flatMap still on the main thread.

Comment: subscribeOn doesn't work with Subject sources. Instead, you should call `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` at the beginning of the chain

Comment: will try and report back, thank you

Comment: No luck with moving the subscribe up. The subscribe on has to be on the current location foo provider call or it fails.